# How to subtract an element from previous one in python?

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I'm doing a script that gives me the difference in profit that represents to buy one more element in my business. I have a list with the monthly input that I get buying one, two, three elements...

Now I want to know the difference in profit in the actual iteration with respect to the previous element in the list.

I have tried:

```
for x in my_list:
    x = list[x] - list[x-1]
```

and some variations of this, but I get the error "

> list index out of range

" because Python don't allow this: list[x] in a for statement.

I have seen solutions to this that need to import some package. But I am learning and I want to do it with the basic tools(for, while, if).

It is possible to do it in this way?

Comment: Yes it is possible though basic tool as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I fully understand but is this what you mean?

```
my_list = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
diff_list = []
for i in range(1,len(my_list)):
    x = my_list[i] - my_list[i-1]
    diff_list.append(x)

print(diff_list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

To get a list of the differences you can do:

```
diffs = [y - x for x, y in zip(my_list, my_list[1:])]
```

This uses [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to allow you to process subsequent elements in the list in a more convenient manner.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an error is because you are incorrectly using a for loop, the x in your for loop is iterations current object in the list.

e.g. for the list `aList = [3, 5, 2, 5, 8, 12]`, on the first iteration x would equal 3, since aList[0] is 3

Also if you used your code with a while loop, it would still give an undesired result

e.g.

```
aList = [3, 5, 2, 5, 8, 12]
x = 0
while x < len(aList):
    aList[x] = aList[x] - aList[x-1]
    x += 1
```

this is because aList[x-1] for the first iteration would be referencing the last element of `aList` (`aList[-1]`) since `x = 0`, so it would be `aList[0] = aList[0] - aList[0-1]` or `aList[0] = 3 - 12`.

My solution would be to enumerate the list, set the original "previous value"(`x_prev`) to 0, and subtract the previous element from the current element.

```py
aList = [3, 5, 2, 5, 8, 12]
x_prev = 0
for i, x_val in enumerate(aList):
    aList[i] -= x_prev
    x_prev = x_val
print(aList)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you try to access python's builtin `list` within your loop instead of your chosen variable name `my_list`.
Second, you overwrite your loop variable x within the loop - not a good idea.

Then, by using `for x in my_list:`, x is already representing each element of the list, not the indices of that list. You can create an iteration over the indices of a list by e.g.

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
```

here i is providing the index, so `my_list[i]` makes sense here.
A better python approch for doing those `range of length of...` constructs is [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).
This function returns a counter *and* the elements of a list while iterating, so you can write:

```
for i, val in enumerate(my_list[1:]):
    x = val - my_list[i]
```

Comment: Thank you @SpghttCd, I wasn't iterating over the index. That was the problem. I don't know why someone downvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,

```
my_list = [1,4,6,8,1,16,47]
y = 0
for x in my_list[1:]:
    x1 = x - my_list[y]
    y = y + 1
    print(x1)
```